# How to detect if last cell is visible in UICollectionView?

Tags: swift, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I am trying to detect if the last cell in a `collectionView` is visible.

```
var isLastCellVisible: Bool {

    let lastIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forItem: self.messages.count - 1, inSection: 0)
    let visibleIndexPaths = self.collectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems()

    let lastCellPositionY = self.collectionView.layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath(lastIndexPath)!.frame.origin.y
    let bottomInset = self.collectionView.contentInset.bottom // changes when the keyboard is shown / hidden
    let contentHeight = self.collectionView.contentSize.height

    if visibleIndexPaths.contains(lastIndexPath) && (contentHeight - lastCellPositionY) > bottomInset {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```

What works:

If the last cell is visible and the keyboard is shown so that the cell is **not hidden** by it, the above code returns true. If it **is hidden** it returns false.

But I can't figure out how to return true, when the user scrolls up and the last cell is above the keyboard.

`lastCellPositionY` and `contentHeight` don't change when the `collectionView` gets scrolled up. 
Instead 
`self.collectionView.bounds.origin.y` does change, but I don't know how to compare `lastCellPositionY` to it, since they don't share the same origin and `self.collectionView.bounds.origin.y` is significantly less than `lastCellPositionY`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this code (translated to Swift from the commits in this thread: https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController/issues/1458)

```
var isLastCellVisible: Bool {

    if self.messages.isEmpty {
        return true
    }

    let lastIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forItem: self.messages.count - 1, inSection: 0)
    var cellFrame = self.collectionView.layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath(lastIndexPath)!.frame

    cellFrame.size.height = cellFrame.size.height

    var cellRect = self.collectionView.convertRect(cellFrame, toView: self.collectionView.superview)

    cellRect.origin.y = cellRect.origin.y - cellFrame.size.height - 100 
    // substract 100 to make the "visible" area of a cell bigger

    var visibleRect = CGRectMake(
        self.collectionView.bounds.origin.x,
        self.collectionView.bounds.origin.y,
        self.collectionView.bounds.size.width,
        self.collectionView.bounds.size.height - self.collectionView.contentInset.bottom
    )

    visibleRect = self.collectionView.convertRect(visibleRect, toView: self.collectionView.superview)

    if CGRectContainsRect(visibleRect, cellRect) {
        return true
    }

    return false
}
```

Answer (score 19):

What i am using

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplayCell cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if indexPath.row == dataSource.count - 1 {
            // Last cell is visible
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

An handy extension with two computed properties for this.

```
extension UICollectionView {

    var isLastItemFullyVisible: Bool {

        let numberOfItems = numberOfItems(inSection: 0)
        let lastIndexPath = IndexPath(item: numberOfItems - 1, section: 0)

        guard let attrs = collectionViewLayout.layoutAttributesForItem(at: lastIndexPath) 
        else { 
            return false 
        }
        return bounds.contains(attrs.frame)
    }

    // If you don't care if it's fully visible, as long as some of it is visible
    var isLastItemVisible: Bool {
       let numberOfItems = collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: 0)
       return indexPathsForVisibleItems.contains(where: { $0.item == numberOfItems - 1 })
    }
}
```

There's an alternative to the isLastItemFullyVisible. A one liner.

```
var isLastItemFullyVisible: Bool {
   contentSize.width == contentOffset.x + frame.width - contentInset.right
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For Swift 3:

```
var isLastCellVisible: Bool {

    if self.posts.isEmpty {
        return true
    }

    let lastIndexPath = IndexPath(item: self.posts.count - 1, section: 1)
    var cellFrame = self.collectionView?.layoutAttributesForItem(at: lastIndexPath)!.frame

    cellFrame?.size.height = (cellFrame?.size.height)!

    var cellRect = self.collectionView?.convert(cellFrame!, to: self.collectionView?.superview)

    cellRect?.origin.y = (cellRect?.origin.y)! - (cellFrame?.size.height)! - 100 
    // substract 100 to make the "visible" area of a cell bigger

    var visibleRect = CGRect(x: (self.collectionView?.bounds.origin.x)!, y: (self.collectionView?.bounds.origin.y)!, width: 
        (self.collectionView?.bounds.size.width)!, height: 
        (self.collectionView?.bounds.size.height)! - (self.collectionView?.contentInset.bottom)!
    )

    visibleRect = (self.collectionView?.convert(visibleRect, to: self.collectionView?.superview))!

    if visibleRect.contains(cellRect!) {
        return true
    }

    return false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5**

```swift
public extension IndexPath {

  func isLastRow(at tableView: UITableView) -> Bool {
    return row == (tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: section) - 1)
  }

  func isLastRow(at collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Bool {
    return row == (collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: section) - 1)
  }
}
```

For CollectionView

```swift
public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath.isLastRow(at: collectionView) {
      ..//
    }
}
```

For TableView

```swift
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath.isLastRow(at: collectionView) {
      ..//
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Swift version 4.2

```
 func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    if (scrollView.bounds.maxY) == scrollView.contentSize.height{
        // Call Your API or hide UIElements
     }
 }
```